# code flow in rackt react-router

Tags: reactjs-flux, react-router, reactjs

I am having difficulty knowing the flow of react-router by (https://github.com/rackt/react-router).

If i have 2 files: routes.js, app.js(entry component) as below:

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route path="/" handler={home}/>
  </Route>
);


module.exports = routes;
```

## app.js

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('../routes.js');
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var App= React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
             <RouteHandler/>
        )
    }

});


module.exports = App;
```

How does the app component gets called? As of traditional way i use following code to render "app" component in app.js.

```
React.render(
    <App />, document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Now what i dont understand is what is the following code doing. Is it replacement of traditional way of rendering, i need to use following code to listen to url and render app.js but not the above code?

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
});
```

What if i am using another js file "main.js" to render "app.js" and now i want to use app.js to handle all the route how do i do it. Mean to say i want to render what ever the route is passed in app.js.

My code in main.js is below:

```
React.render(
    <APP />, document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to update your App.js file to grab the correct `react-router` module. You're assigning the export of your `routes.js` file to `Router`, but it should be `react-router`. Node will actually cache the result of the module and reuse it for every other reference to it.

Your approach would work ok -- typically you see something like a `Main.js` file to handle the routing, and the `App.js` is more of the wrapper for your component(s).

So I would make a `Main.js` file like so..

```js
// Main.js
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('../routes.js');
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

Router.run(routes, function(Handler, state) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.body);
});
```

Then, just make your `App.js` mount the `RouteHandler` and handle any other parent state. When you navigate to the route, it will match it in the `Router.run` function and then all routes in the 'family' of the matched route will be rendered.

Comment: You also might want to use `DefaultRoute` in your `routes` instead of `<Route path="/" ... />`.